# How can I extract color values from an EPS file?

Tags: vector, ghostscript, postscript, eps

I'm trying to find all fill and stroke values used in an EPS file. I can parse the file, I just can't figure out how color values are defined in the EPS postscript section. I have converted the file to SVG (using ghostscript) and I can get the hex values, but an EPS to SVG conversion with a gradient produces files 20x the size. Is there a standard format for color values in postscript that I can extract from an EPS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostScript is a programming language, not a simple file format, so there is no simple way to determine what is going on in the program.

A gradient may well be defined as a smooth shading in PostScript, which is a high level construct with no equivalent in SVG, so it will be rendered as an image (hence the explosion in size).

You can use the fact that PostScript is a programming language by redefining the basic operations, and using that to get the information you want. For example, to find the colour being used for a stroke you might do :

```
/OriginalStroke /stroke load def
/stroke {
(Current colour space = ) print currentcolorspace == flush
(current colour = ) print mark currentcolor counttomark -1 1 { -1 roll 20 string cvs print ( ) print} for flush pop
OriginalStroke
} bind def
```

Of course you will need to be prepared to cope with the rich variety of possible colour spaces in PostScript; Gray, RGB, CMYK, Separation, DeviceN, CIEBasedA, CIEBasedABC, CIEBasedDEF, CIEBasedDEFG, Indexed and Pattern.

Possibly you don';t need to know the original values, I'm guessing this is true because conversion to SVG will, I think, convert all colours to RGB, so perhaps you only want the RGB equivalents. In which case you could simply use:

```
(current colour in RGB = ) print currentrgbcolor 3 -1 roll == exch == == flush
```

I don't know how you wold handle a fill with a Pattern colour though :-)

Perhaps if you explained why you want to know this it would be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. My goal here is to extract the hex values most used in a vector image (EPS input). I tried doing this by rasterizing the vector then parsing the histogram, but the color values are off after the image is rasterized. When converting an EPS to an SVG and then parsing the output I was able to extract precise hex values, but this causes an explosion in size and takes awhile to process. How can I run your command (current color in RGB) on an EPS file from the command line?

Comment: Its a bit big to execute from the command line, put it in a file and execute that file immediately before the one you want to sample. ie 'gs <options> file1.ps file2.eps

Comment: Interesting idea. I executed 'gs color.ps myfile.eps' and I get an output of 'current colour in RGB = 0.0' at the top of my color.ps file is %!PS. It does not appear to run color.ps on myfile.eps. What am I missing?

Comment: Err, that line was supposed to be inserted into the 'OriginalStroke' procedure in place of the initial 2 lines '(Current colour space = )...' and '(current colour = )...' On its own it won't do anything useful. What the code does is replace the 'stroke' operator with a procedure which gets the information you want, and then executes the previous definition of stroke. Obviously you will need similar code for fill, eofill, rectstroke, rectfill, ustroke, ufill and ueofill for completeness. I don't know what you want to do with shfill which is more complex, or Pattern spaces.

Comment: This is the direction I'm looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the size of the bit image should not really matter if all you do is get a histogram and throw it away:

```
 pstopnm -stdout file.ps | ppmhist
```

I *assume* everyone has netpbm...netpbm.sourceforge.net

Comment: I'm going to give this a run, but wont this rasterize the image so the color values from the EPS will be incorrect? I'm trying to achieve extract accurate color values.

Comment: The image will be rendered, yes, and will be converted to RGB. Note as I mentioned above that there are *lots* of colour spaces in PostScript not just RGB. How do you plan to handle Patterns ? If I fill a rectangle with a pattern are the colour values used to draw the pattern used once, or as many times as required to tile the area ? If you render to a bitmap, then the result will be 'as many times as required to tile the area'

Comment: i guess its unclear what the desired output is. If a page uses a bunch of different color spaces do you want all that info: this page uses the following color spaces with a list of color specs in each color space?  Otherwise its not clear what you mean by "exact"

Comment: I would like to have textual output for each color in its relative colorspace, RGB, CMYK, Gray, etc. When I rasterize a vector image my color values are distorted, which is why I'm trying to figure out how to extract the values from the PostScript programming directly. KenS idea is interesting, executing a PS command on the EPS to extract the values.