# How to handle slow rendering SVG images?

Tags: html, performance, svg, rendering, freeze

We are building a mobile app that uses an embedded webview to display an operator's manual that has a lot of technical illustrations in it. The illustrations are coming from EPS vector files that we convert to SVG to get crisp and scalable images.

Unfortunately we have a few cases where the images get very big and slow. For example we have one SVG image which is 4.5MB and consists of 23000 individual paths. This image shows almost instantly on iOS but takes about 4 seconds to render on a modern Android phone which severely degrades the user experience.

We have thousands of operator's manuals in dozens of languages so we can't really do any manual tweaks on individual images. With this constraint, what are the best strategies do handle slow rendering SVG images?

Comment: Draw fewer lines. Is every one of those lines crucial to the image? Do they all need to be displayed at the same time or could some only be displayed if the user has zoomed into a smaller area i.e. are they detail that could normally be omitted?

Comment: If the issues occur on Chrome, post a bug report to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues with one of your examples, explain the dramatic performance differences. In my experience performance has very high priority and you have a good chance that this will be improved for future releases.

Comment: I have seen these large numbers in the past mostly for grafics containing color gradients. As I understand it, some gradient models in Postscript are incompatible to the one in SVG, so on import they get converted to a large number of layered solid-color shapes (or [even to raster images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680747)). You could try to do the conversion with different libraries (poppler, Cairo, Inkscape, or even [dvisgm](https://dvisvgm.de/), which I just came about for the first time in a Google search.)

Comment: Unfortunately, Blink (the rendering engine used in all Chromium-based browsers) is not the fastest at rendering complex SVGs. We're developing an image / vector editing application that uses SVG for rendering and running into the same issues. It's probably not a priority for browser developers so maybe this is to be expected, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If the SVGs only consist of paths and shapes with a single solid color the only option you have is trying to somehow simplify the SVG. Merge shapes, flatten groups, etc.

For example if two paths have the same color, transform, opacity, etc., you can merge their path data. This is done by removing one of the paths and simply concatenating the path data of both paths.

Here is an example with two paths, each nested in a group:

```
<g fill="#1b8f00">
    <path d="M80 80 A45 45,0,0,0,125 125L125 80Z" />
</g>
<g fill="#1b8f00">
    <path d="M30 20 A25 25,0,1,0,45 25L45 30Z" />
</g>
```

By moving the `fill` attribute into the path and concatenating the path data `d` of both paths this can be simplified to:

```
<path color="#1b8f00" d="M80 80 A45 45,0,0,0,125 125L125 80ZM30 20 A25 25,0,1,0,45 25L45 30Z" />
```

If your SVG uses filters and masks there are some other things you can try. But usually iOS is much slower than Android in these cases, so it looks like this does not apply to your images.